# Creating database with same structure but different name

Tags: mysql, database

i have a database with name "DB_General" i want to create separate data base for each user

according to his name like"DB_User1". i want to use the same structure for "DB_User1" as

given in "DB_General". is there any way to do this, i am using MySQL database in JSP.

Comment: A separate database for each user?!  You've got to be kidding!

Comment: A separate database for each user? Perhaps you mean a separate table for each user? I don't claim to be an expert in databases, but if you're thinking of making a separate db for each user, then you might need to rethink your design.

Comment: @awm: i am not kidding man, its user requirement, i tell you little bit about that, look if i provide u facility to create clinic in website where u can add doctor, nurse, admin etc... if you have only 1000 patients at each clinic and you have 50 clinics in your DB then how can u handle them, so i just want to create separate DB for each clinic so i just have to mange one Db at a time and i will be efficient.

Comment: In multi-tenant systems, this isn't so abnormal.  Sometimes, clients actually require in their contracts that they have a dedicated database to avoid commingling data with other clients.  If you never need to report across multiple clients' data, it actually is kind of good to separate it.  The main downside is that you now have to try to keep a bunch of schemas in sync, and it also can make it tricky to build one system on top of hundreds of unique databases.  You could also consider creating client-specific tables in a single database, rather than dedicated databases.

Answer (score 0):

make a backup of DB_General eg using mysqldump, remove data if needed and restore it under different database name like DB_User_1

however idea of creating separate database for each user seems to be far way from wise

Answer (score 0):

Run the following programmatically from a shell:

```
mysqladmin --user=foo --password=bar create DB_User1

mysqldump --user=foo --password=bar --no-data DB_general | mysql --user=foo --password=bar DB_User1
```